# Ruby Sketchup, get a value from an open excel workbook

Tags: ruby, excel

Is there a way I can get a value from an all ready open workbook?

I can get a value by opening the workbook, but I would like to get the value when the workbook is already opened.

```
    require 'win32ole'

xl = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
xl.visible=1

wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\Dave\Downloads\Example.xlsm')

worksheet = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
worksheet2 = wb.Worksheets('Sheet2')

worksheet.Range('a1').Value=1111
worksheet.Range('a2').Value
```

What I am doing is inputing data into excel, then I have a ruby code in sketchup that get the data and draws from it. It then places the drawing into the worksheet.
That's why I would like the ruby code to be able to read the data when the sheet is opened.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes you can connect the existing one by `excel = WIN32OLE::connect('excel.Application')`

Comment: Yes, you have the object now, so you can use it like when you use opening the excel file using the open statement. I have added a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way

```
excel = WIN32OLE.connect("excel.application")
workbook = excel.Workbooks('workbook name')
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets('Sheet1')
```

Comment: Changed in my answer.